# How to handle PJSIP NOTIFY

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm using PJSIP 2.11 on an Android app that I'm developing and I need to handle an incoming SIP NOTIFY.

I can see the NOTIFY in the logs with the content type "application/json" but I can't find the callback in PJSIP to be able to handle it on the "Android" side.

How can I handle this? Do I need to change the PJSIP code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for `on_buddy_state` or `on_buddy_evsub_state` callback ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__callback.htm#a7e24d87e82ee2c4c1a68efa3cbf6b902)).

Comment: This is used only for presence, right? In my case the received NOTIFY has information about number of unread voicemails.

Comment: It doesn't matter what information you're passing. In on_buddy_evsub_state you can get the message body. To interpret of it's content is up to you.